# Pushing Android app updates on getjar.com

Tags: android

I plan to publish my Android app on getjar.com . However, I am unable to see how the user would be notified of any updates. Does GetJar support app updates (i.e. would the user be notified of app updates when new versions are uploaded  to getjar.com ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, getjar doesn't but you can notify the user in the app that the update is available to download from getjar.You can set time in your app e.g after 24hrs check the server for updates.

Comment: Is there a standard library/method for checking for updates, or do I host the latest version number somewhere and check if current is lower than it?

Comment: no there is no standard library.you have to deal with it through your own web service.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking, we actually just rolled out update notifications for Android apps. You can find out how to update your app here: http://blog.getjar.com/developer/howtoupdates/